# Changing/Adding Java applet parameters from within applet

Tags: java, applet

Is there a way to change/add applet parameters from within applet itself?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, as opposed to simply changing the relevant attributes entirely within the applet code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think so. Applet parameters are defined on HTML page, are read by browser and passed to applet by java plug in via applet context. Even if you run code via LiveConnect and change dynamically the parameters of applet when applet is running it will not get new values because  java plugin will not call its `init()` method again.

The big question is why do you need this? If you read some parameter from applet parameters you assign it to some variable inside applet. Do you want to change the value of this variable at runtime? Just do it, i.e. assign new value to this internal variable of applet.

Comment: The only reason is a debugging purposes. My applet performs redirect at some point to a new location. According to redirect url, my webserver adds parameters in to html. I want to debug different values for parameters without aditing html, during run time. However this is not a must.